# Partial Derivative of Trace of Matrix in negative power wrt to parameters

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, trace

$\renewcommand{\v}[1]{\mathrm{vec}\left(#1\right)}
\renewcommand{\m}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\trace}[1]{\mathrm{trace}\left(#1\right)}
\renewcommand{\diag}[1]{\mathrm{diag}\left(#1\right)}$

Suppose we have the diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D} = diag(\mathbf{HW1})$, where $W$ is diagonal and known and $1$ is a column vector with ones. $A$ and $B$ are known matrices, also.

How can we calculate the partial derivative of the following wrt matrix calculus? $$\frac{\partial \trace{\mathbf A \mathbf D^{-1/2} \mathbf B)}}{\partial\m H}$$

This can be written as $$\frac{\partial \trace{\mathbf B\mathbf A \mathbf D^{-1/2} }}{\partial\m H} = \frac{\partial \trace{\mathbf{S} \mathbf D^{-1/2} }}{\partial\m H}  = \trace {\frac{\partial {\mathbf{S} \mathbf D^{-1/2}} }{\partial\m H}}$$

Except for the analytical way, I couldn't find out in matrix cookbook something that can show me the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the operation $B={\rm Diag}(b)$ which takes a vector and returns a diagonal matrix,

and the operation $b={\rm diag}(B)$ which extracts the diagonal of a matrix into a vector.

Since $W$ is a diagonal matrix we can write it as $W={\rm Diag}(w)$ for some vector $w$.

The result of multiplying this matrix by a column of ones is simply $\,w=W1$.

Define some new variables 
$$\eqalign{
S &= BA, \quad &s &= {\rm diag}(S) = {\rm diag}(S^T) \cr
g &= Hw, \quad &G &= {\rm Diag}(g), \quad dg = dH\,w \cr
}$$
Write the function of interest in terms of these new variables.

Then calculate its differential and its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= {\rm Tr}(SG^{-1/2}) = S^T:G^{-1/2} = s:g^{-1/2} \cr
d\phi &= s:dg^{-1/2} \cr
  &= s:(-\tfrac{1}{2}g^{-3/2}\odot dg) \cr
  &= -\tfrac{1}{2}s:G^{-3/2}dg \cr
  &= -\tfrac{1}{2}G^{-3/2}s:dH\,w \cr
  &= -\tfrac{1}{2}G^{-3/2}sw^T:dH \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial H}
 &= -\tfrac{1}{2}G^{-3/2}sw^T \cr
 &= -\tfrac{1}{2}{\rm Diag}(HW1)^{-3/2}\,{\rm diag}(BA)\,1^TW \cr
}$$
where functions on vectors are applied elementwise,

and $(\odot)$ represents the elementwise/Hadamard product,

 and $(\,:\,)$ represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $\,A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$.

**NB:**  The cyclic property of the trace allows Frobenius products to be rearranged in numerous ways.

For example
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= B^TA:C \cr&= AC^T:B \cr&= BC:A \cr&= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
}$$
are all equivalent.

Comment: Greg, your answer is incredible and thank you very much! I have a question. Which property did you use in order :dH to appear as a denumerator of partial \phi? (almost at the end of the main part of the solution).

Comment: Do you think I can follow the way you showed in order to solve $$  trace ({\frac{\partial {\mathbf{S} \mathbf D^{-1}} }{\partial H}}), where\, \mathbf{D} = Diag(\mathbf{1}^{T} \mathbf{H})$$ ?

Comment: The trace is only defined for square matrices (and scalars if treated as $1\times 1$ matrices). Unfortunately, the quantity $$\frac{\partial(SD^{-1})}{\partial H}$$ is not a matrix, but rather a fourth-order tensor. For the second question, if it is known that the differential of a function is given by $$df = G\,dx$$ for _**any**_ value of $dx$, then the quantity $G$ _**must be**_ the gradient of the function. There is no _division_ taking place, rather an _identification_ that the only quantity having this property is the gradient. And the gradient is often written using Leibniz notation.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Greg!